# Herkunft von "Versuch nicht, uns ein X für ein U vorzumachen"

Tags: etymology, phrase

Ich glaube, dass ich die Bedeutung dieses Ausdrucks verstehe. Ich möchte aber wissen, warum die Buchstaben "X" und "U" hier eigentlich benützt werden.

Comment: Jetzt denke ich an eine andere Ausdruck mit Buchstaben: Wer A sagt, muss auch B sagen.

Comment: "an eine*n* andere*n* Ausdruck"

Comment: @celtschk : Danke.

Answer (score 13):

Ein wahrscheinlicher Ursprung sind die lateinischen Zahlen X und V (welches im Lateinischen derselbe Buchstabe wie U war).

Wenn der Wirt aus dem V auf dem Bierdeckel ein X macht, hat er dir ein X für ein U vorgemacht und du zahlst das Doppelte.

---

[Jemandem ein X für ein U vormachen](http://www.redensarten.net/X+fuer+ein+U.html)

Comment: Interessant. Den hätte ich vielleicht in die andere Richtung gesagt.

Comment: Hübsche Erklärung.

Comment: Ich kenne die Variante mit dem [Rechenbrett](http://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rechnen_auf_Linien). Die Wandlung vom X zum U war nur ein kleines Verrücken des Rechenpfennigs.

Comment: Schöne Erklärung mit einem kleinen Verbesserungsvorschlag. Der mit der Wendung gemeinte Sachverhalt wird doch eher durch das folgende Bild beschrieben: Ein Gast will zu seinem Vorteil dem Wirt glauben machen, dass das X auf dem Deckel eigentlich ein unsauber geschriebenes V sei...

Comment: Diese Erklaerung hat auch damals in der Schule mein Lateinlehrer gebracht: Er meinte, dass Wirte bei besoffenen Gaesten gerne aus dem V (fuer 5) unbemerkt durch anfuegen von zwei Strichen ein X (fuer 10) machten. Ich finde das plausibel.

Comment: @Ray: Wenn ich die Redewendung richtig verstehe, wird aber doch das "X vorgemacht" (also vorgetäuscht), "für" das (also an Stelle des) "V". Das "V" müsste also die richtige Variante sein. Oder hat sich die Bedeutung von "vormachen" hier umgekehrt?